# Populate text fields with ajax call

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, api

I have an MVC project for filling out forms with user information. Once recorded it gets a unique Id associated with all the details in the form.

I then have a page to edit the form if needed which takes the id into to the url and assigns the Id to Viewbag.Id. I'm trying to use the Id in an ajax call to then pull the rest of the information from the web api and populate the fields with the details that have already been filled out. My problem is that I'm still learning ajax and not 100% on how to accomplish this. Below is what I think is relevant.

My Controller

```
        [Route("EditUser/{id}")]
        [CustomAuthorize(Roles = UserRole.Any)]
        public ActionResult EditUserDetails(int id)
        {
            var userDetails = _slg_Entity.NewUser.FirstOrDefault(z => z.Id == id);

            ViewBag.Id = userDetails.Id;         

            return View($"~/Views/Request/EditUser.cshtml");
        }
```

I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
         $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: "@Url.Action("UserDetails", "Api/Request")",
             data: {
                 Id: "@ViewBag.Id" <--- ID passed to the api controller
             }
         }).done(function (data) {
             $(".firstname").val(variable); <--- assign the data from api to field value
         }).fail(function (error) {
             displayError(error);
         });
```

Api controller:

```
        [Route("UserDetails")]
        [HttpGet]
        [CustomApiAuthorize(Roles = UserRole.HR)]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetUserDetails([FromUri] NewUserDetails existingUser)
        {
            var details = await _slg_Entity.NewUser.FirstOrDefaultAsync(z => z.Id == existingUser.Id);

            existingUser.FirstName = details.FirstName;

            return Ok(details);
        }
```

Not sure if I'm close or in the ball park, so any advice is welcome!
Thanks.

Comment: Is the problem that the code in your question is not working, or is the question about how to complete something not shown here? BR

Comment: @RoarS, It's more the question of am I in the on the right path with this. I'm not getting anything back at the moment,  so the code doesn't work. Basically looking for some pointers or documentation that would help with this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the data was getting passed through fine. I just figured out I was calling it incorrectly.

instead of just passing the variable I created in my controller, I forget to include the data prefix.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "@Url.Action("UserDetails", "Api/Request")",
    data: {
       Id: "@ViewBag.Id"
    }
}).done(function (data) {
   $(".firstname").val(data.variable); 
}).fail(function (error) {
   displayError(error);
});
```